# Force vertical div to full container height

Tags: html, css

I know it's shaky to get a full screen height div without using client-side scripting, but what about this: assuming my div is tall enough to reach the bottom, how do I make it reach the VERY top and bottom, without the little extra space at top and bottom? I've tried adding top and bottom margins (and even padding) of 0px, but it doesn't seem to work.

```css
#container {
    height: 1000px;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

Comment: You can use absolute positioning. Set `top: 0` and `bottom: 0`. You can also use `height: 100%`, but you need to set it on all parent elements as well, including the `html` element.

Comment: You need to make html and body 100% tall as well: `html, body{height:100%;}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change `height: 1000px;` to `height: 100%;`

Comment: That will only work if all the parent elements also have `height: 100%` set.

Comment: True. I just assumed OP would have that. My bad!